# Xcode Implementing scroll with animation

Tags: xcode, animation, scroll, label

How to implement a scroller to one of the labels before reaching the top of the screen has remained at the top, and the text scrolls from another label beyond the limits of the screen, such as in instagramm, except instead of photos text from the second label

Answer (score 0):

Scroll View

scroller to one of the labels before reaching the top of the screen has remained at the top, and the text scrolls from another label beyond the limits of the screen,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mws6Zbq_y6c

Darwich

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.